# @EJB dependency injection query regarding Local Stateless Session bean (EJB 3.x)

Tags: ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

I have 2 EJB projects.

- Ejb1
- Ejb2

#### Ejb1 has Stateless Local Session bean.

```
package p1;    

@Stateless
public class CallerNew implements CallerLocal {
```

#### Ejb2 has Stateless Remote Session bean.

```
package p2;

@Stateless  
public class MobilePhone implements MobilePhoneRemote {  

@EJB(mappedName="CallerNew/local-p1.CallerLocal")
CallerLocal caller;
```

I deployed both the projects individually in the same server (JBoss v5.0).

The server registers CallerLocal also in Global JNDI namespace.

The question is even though I have made the CallerLocal as Local session bean, I can still get its reference through the JNDI from a separate EJB project which I thought is only possible if both the EJB projects are packaged into an EAR.

Is this behavior correct? please explain.

Comment: found this article. Exactly what I needed.  
[Communication between EJB modules in the same Application Server](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/communication-between-ejb-modules-in-the-same-application-server)